# how to validate a textbox length in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, validation, customvalidator, rangevalidator

In VB.NET , I am trying to validate a

> `<asp:textbox id="name" runat=server> </asp:textbox>`

textbox value  which should not exceed more than 200 characters and the textbox takes only string.

Which validator will be a good option ? i want to use custom validator, will it work with string values?

Comment: Asp.Net TextBox control, or Windows Forms TextBox?

Comment: You can use custom validator, and in `OnServerValidate` event check string length and return `isvalid` `true` or `false`.

Comment: Why don't you like `<asp:TextBox MaxLength="200" id="name" runat=server> </asp:TextBox>` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexTextBox1"
 ControlToValidate="YourTextBoxID" runat="server" 
 ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,200}$" Text="200 characters max" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the use of custom validator altogether.
If you only need to force the max length of a text box field you have this at your disposal

```
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="200" id="name" runat=server> </asp:TextBox>
```